# DataSpell Group/Collapse cells in sections

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, markdown, dataspell

I have been using DataSpell for a while and found it a very nice IDE. However, I don't know how to do the Group/Collapse cells in sections, like what I did in Jupyter notebook. Anybody can help me with that?